# Insert an entry into hash using put

Tags: hash-tables

```
(defvar-local hash-entries nil)
(put 'hash-entries "key" "val")
(message "%S" hash-entries)
```

I try to add a `key-value` pair to the hash variable, `hash-entries` using the function `put`.

But when i print it, it prints `nil` instead of its contents, `(key . val)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`put` is not for hash tables. What you want is `puthash`.

> (puthash KEY VALUE TABLE)
>
> Associate KEY with VALUE in hash table TABLE.

Also you cannot just use `puthash` on nil, you need to actually create a hash table first with `make-hash-table`. If you want to use strings as the has keys make sure you pass `:test 'equal` to `make-hash-table`.

For all the information you need to use hash tables you can consult [this part](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html) of the manual.

---

`put` is for storing properties on a symbol, not the symbols value. You can read more about what put actually does [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Properties.html). It's extremely rare that you would actually ever need to use `put` for something.